# Automatically add a new row of data every 5 min

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

i have certain data in a range in Sheet3, say as an example, A1 to H1. This data keeps updating automatically every 5 min.

How to to copy this data to another Sheet4? Every update should add a new row of data every 5min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Application.Wait to loop your code every 5 minutes. Here's an example of how you can do it every second, for 10 seconds. While testing I suggest you always use a time limit to avoid infinite loop and smaller amounts of time to make sure everything is right, then you just change the times using "hh:mm:ss" format. You could use Copy/Paste commands, or set cell values directly, like I did in this example.

```
Sub CpValues_Loop()
    tStop = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10") '"hh:mm:ss" Limit time to avoid infinite loop while testing
    r = 1 'first row to paste values
    Do Until t > tStop
        CpValues (r)
        r = r + 1
        DoEvents 'refresh screen
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        t = Now
    Loop
End Sub
Sub CpValues(r)
    For i = 1 To 8
        Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(r, i) = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

EDIT

As suggested by Simon, a public Boolean would be right to Start/Stop the Loop, then you can insert buttons to call the Start and Stop functions. About using Wait or Timer, I think it depends on Excel versions and if you need to change things or not during the loop. I didn't know Timer until now, but it looks nice, his solution worked well here, just choose what works best for you.

```
Public CpStop As Boolean
Sub CpValues_Loop()
    tStop = Now + TimeValue("00:00:20") '"hh:mm:ss" Limit time to avoid infinite loop while testing
    CpStop = False
    'Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:H100").ClearContents 'to clear and test again
    r = 1 'first row to paste values
    Do Until t > tStop Or CpStop = True
        CpValues (r)
        r = r + 1
        DoEvents 'refresh screen
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        DoEvents
        t = Now
    Loop
End Sub
Sub CpValues(r)
    For i = 1 To 8
        Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(r, i) = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, i)
    Next i
End Sub
Sub CpValues_Stop()
    CpStop = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, as of now its working fine. So much grateful for your help bro! If i wish to let it run continuously, i can add a Start and a Stop commandbutton to control that right? should i call the fn in start and what should i put in stop?

Comment: I would suggest the use of `Timer` or  `Application.Ontime` because `Application.Wait` doesn't only freeze the VBA code but also the entire application.

Comment: Hi Simon, how would u incorporate Timer or Application.Ontime in the above code?

Comment: @Soccent4500X Well if you run this does it freeze it for you, or are you able to continue using Excel fine? And/or do you need to?

Comment: it does not freeze and the update keeps happening without any issue

Answer (score 1):

For some people `Application.Wait` freezes the whole application (me for one) so I tend to avoid it. Not sure why it happens, but it does, so instead I tend to go with `Timer` or `Application.OnTime` which works better for me. Here is what I came up with below. This will continuously loop every 5 minutes until it is stopped. I've included an extra sub which you can link to a button to stop to code at any time just using a public boolean.

My code also just grabs the range instead of looping through each column as well.

```
Public StopCopy As Boolean

Sub Copy_Loop()

Dim EndTime As Long, i As Long, sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet3") 'Set as your sheet to copy from
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet4") 'Your sheet to copy to
EndTime = 300 'Amount of time to wait in seconds (300 = 5 mins)
StopCopy = False
i = 1 'Your starting row

NextCopy:
t = Timer
sht2.Range("A" & i, "H" & i).Value = sht1.Range("A1:H1").Value 'Copying range A:H. Change columns as needed
i = i + 1 'Move to next row to paste new data to after time is up

Do While Timer < t + EndTime
    If StopCopy = True Then
        MsgBox "Copy Loop has been stopped.", vbInformation, "Process stopped" 'Msgbox so user knows looping has stopped. Remove if unwanted.
        Exit Sub
    End If
    DoEvents 'Keep Excel operational
Loop

GoTo NextCopy

End Sub

Sub Stop_Copy_Loop()

StopCopy = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but in fact running this code hangs my excel as i think it waits 5 min to add the next line of data and till then, excel bcomes un responsive

Comment: That is the point it waits 5 minutes to copy the data. It's strange but I guess it must be to do with versions of Excel or systems or both etc. `Application.Wait` hangs my system but I tested this and I could continue using excel just fine while it ran so not sure why it hangs for you. Oh well someone might find this useful if they come across this post.

Comment: You put this entirely into a module right? It needs the `Public StopCopy As Boolean` line to be outside of the sub (top of module).

Comment: yes, entrie thing into a module and StopCopy as a Public variable outside the module.

Comment: i have Excel 2013 btw

Comment: I just realised it was missing the `End If`. Did you not get an error trying this? (I didn't because I changed the If statement from 1 line to 2 and didn't test that part afterwards).

Comment: @ Simon how would I add a time stamp into your code above to make sure the timer is accurately copying every 5 minutes. I've used `Application.OnTime` in the past and it would skip some copy cycles so hopefully this `timer` works better.

Comment: @mjac Well it should be accurate. Timer is a constant second counter from Midnight using your computers clock. So if it's say 5000 then its 5000 seconds since midnight. It actually goes down to the millisecond as well so you can use timer for a fraction of a second. If you wanted reassurance then right before or after the copy (I don't know where you want the timestamp to go) you just put something like `Range("A1") = Now`. The `Now` function gives you the full time and date.

Comment: @Simon Thanks. I would like the time stamp to go in A1 but stamp each time there after the cycle loops. So in the example above you are copying A:H but when it copies to the other sheet the time stamp would go in A then A:H would go in B:I. As all of column A is reserved for the stamp.

Comment: @mjac Do you mean you want the timestamp to move down the rows with each copy as well? If so then you can just do `Range("A" & i) = Now` or replace i with another variable if the starting row is different etc. If you add it in where I said it will happen every time it copies.

Comment: @Simon Yes, that is what I meant. Works perfect. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @Simon I loaded the code in my workbook and I have other code contained in other worksheets. The code contains `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()` events and once I run the `timer` the `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()` events stop. I know this is a very general question but any idea why the code above would stop other worksheet scripts from running?

Comment: @mjac I don't know sorry. I just created and tested a dummy file and the `Worksheet_Calculate` still worked while the timer was running So I don't know what your issue is then. You may want to pose a new question to the board as we're veering off track from the original on this one. That way others could see/help you if needed.

Comment: @Simon it cool. I  just realized its also stopping all my RTDs so its more than the `Worksheet_Calculate` will do thanks.